# display wordcloud with ggarrange and qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-cloud

I am trying to get word cloud graphs from the R wordcloud package to show up using ggarrange but they are not. The wordcloud code looks like this:

```
Essay_wc[[cor]] <- wordcloud(d_essay$word, d_essay$freq, colors=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"), min.freq=10, max.words=800, scale=c(3,.4), random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35)
```

the other graphs I am using in ggarrange look like this

```
 
  emo_plot[[cor]] <- qplot(sentiment, xlab="After Essay emotions", data=td_emo, weight=count, geom="bar",fill=sentiment)+ggtitle(pdfNames[cor])+theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9, lineheight = .9,family = "Times", face = "bold.italic", colour = "red")) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 9, lineheight = .9,family = "Times", face = "bold.italic", colour = "red"))
  
  
  
  sentiment_plot[[cor]] <- qplot(sentiment, xlab ="After Essay sentiments in binary terms", data=td_sentiment, weight=count, geom="bar",fill=sentiment)+ggtitle(pdfNames[cor])+theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9, lineheight = .9,family = "Times", face = "bold.italic", colour = "red")) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 9, lineheight = .9,family = "Times", face = "bold.italic", colour = "red"))
```

The ggarrange code looks like this:

```
graphsList=list()
for(i in 1:length(my_corpus)){  #length(my_corpus)
  graphsList=c(graphsList,emo_plotB[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,sentiment_plotB[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,emo_plot[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,sentiment_plot[i])
}

pdf("BeforeAndAfterIrreg.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
#do.call(ggarrange, c(graphsList, list(ncol = 2, nrow=3, rremove("x.text"), align="hv" ) ))
do.call(ggarrange, c(graphsList, list(ncol = 2, nrow=4, rremove("x.text") ) )) #align="hv"
dev.off()
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this? I tried this but it doesn't show the wordcloud

```
graphsList=list()
for(i in 1:length(my_corpus)){  #length(my_corpus)
  graphsList=c(graphsList,emo_plotB[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,sentiment_plotB[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,emo_plot[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,sentiment_plot[i])
  graphsList=c(graphsList,Essay_wc[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wordcloud` returns `NULL` so you cannot store it in `Essay_wc[[cor]]`. Try using other methods which return the wordcloud plot. For example with `ggwordcloud` package.

```
library(ggwordcloud)
library(ggplot2)


Essay_wc[[cor]] <- ggplot(d_essay, aes(label = word, size = freq)) +
                    geom_text_wordcloud()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestion. Works!